# Как в PHP вычислить завтрашнюю дату

Tags: php

Нужно вычислить завтрашнюю дату чтоб PHP делал одно если завтра 31ое или другое если 1ое
кто сталкивался помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Есть конструкция, которая возвращает следующий день:

```
$d = strtotime("+1 day");
echo date("d.m.Y", $d);       //выведет завтра в формате дд.мм.гггг
```

Дальше условие на соответствие даты, думаю не  проблема

PS: не забываем что в php timestamp  это количество секунд, прошедших с полуночи 1 января 1970 г.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <?php
> $first = time();
> sleep(24*60*60);
> $last = time();
>
> echo "Начали: " . date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $first) . "<br />";
> echo "Результат: " . date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $last);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

немного дополню
 можно получить кастомный завтра

```
[завтра нашего дня] = strtotime('+1 day', strtotime('наш день'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Я пробовал, вроде нормально:

```
<?php
$d=strtotime("+1 day");
echo date("d-m-Y",$d);
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Вариант:

```
("d.m.Y", time() + 3600);
```

Comment: Ну тогда уже так date("d.m.Y", time()+3600*25);
Вы безграмотный программист, советую самому поучиться

Comment: @Александр Захаров..., зачем Вы 1 час прибавляете ?

Но, даже если Вы прибавите 24 часа, то все равно это будет неверно (вспомните о зимнем/летнем времени).

Comment: А причем тут вообще летнее/зимнее время, если оно отменено?

Comment: @tooq, а вдруг Вашу программу решат запустить там, где оно действует (в мире много стран) ? Или для интервала лет, когда оно действовало ?

А дело тут в том, что при переходе (осенью) с летнего на зимнее в сутках добавляется лишний час. Добавив в "неудачное время" 24 часа к текущему Вы в следующий день не попадете.